# Facebook Canvas-friendly Theme

Tags: social-network

I'm very new to Drupal and web dev in general (J2SE C/ObjC background). I've just installed [Drupal For Facebook](http://drupal.org/project/fb). With its help I'm able to get my FB App to get its content from my Drupal site. However, none of the standard Drupal themes seem to format nicely for facebook.

My criteria are:

- formats pages to < 520 pixels wide (main criteria)
- shows the page contents but very little else (no breadcrumbs or menus)

I thought about writing my own theme to achieve this end. But I thought I'd ask if there's anything readily available out there that I can use, since I can't be the first guy that wants this. Or if there's a way to constraint the page width and hide the menus and breadcrumbs using only CSS trickery, I'd love to know about it too (mind you I'm an HTML noob here)

Gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My thoughts in a nutshell:

- Start with the [Zen base theme](https://drupal.org/project/zen)
- Sub theme this with your custom theme (there are instruction in the Zen theme on how to do this)
- Use a fixed width option, and resize the main column to 520px
- Add CSS to spice it up and give it colours etc (out of the box it is fairly boring colour wise)

In order to hide breadcrumbs you can override the page.tpl.php to not display them.